# Baffling bit of notation

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

So I'm reading a paper about deriving polynomial invariants for links in an arbitrary surface, and I'm stuck on some under explained notation.

The full quote states that something is a 'right module over the Noetherian Ring

$\mathbb{Z}[H_1\Gamma \times \mathbb{Z}^d] \simeq (\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}^{2g}])[t_1^{\pm1}, \ldots, t_d^{\pm1}]$

Where in this case $H_1\Gamma$ is (if I've read this correctly) the quotient group of deck transformations of the covering space by the commutator group, the $t_i$s are meridians of link components and $g$ is the genus of the surface.

I'm not fully sure, however, about $(\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}^{2g}])$ and it's not explained in the paper. Any takers?

Comment: This may help... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring although I could be completely off, so apologies if it's not relevant.

Comment: Thanks - I understand the basic square bracket notation for polynomials over a ring, but I've never seen it used in this recursive fashion. It might indeed just mean 'a ring over a ring over a ring' but I'm not sure why you'd do that, and there's stuff later in the paper that suggests otherwise.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z^{2g}}]$ I think they might mean the "group ring" which typically uses the notation $R[G]$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring). I think the whole expression is a polynomial ring with variables $t_i^\pm$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z^{2g}}]$. Can you tell us what paper it's from, or provide a link?

Comment: Thanks! The paper is called 'invariants of links in thickened surfaces', and it's here: (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513715907). I'm trying to follow through the purely algebraic way of constructing the representation matrix discussed at the opening of section 4. I can see how it's done in the 'diagram trickery' way, but I'm starting work on extending the idea in the paper to other situations. I feel like if I can get to the matrix of example 4.3 myself I'm better able to do this.